# $ not defined and Jquery not working locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the latest uncompressed jquery file downloaded locally and within the same file directory as my javascript file. My script tag directed toward jquery is before my main javascript file, but it doesn't seem to load.

Inside my head, I have:

`<script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
 <script src="main.js"></script>`

The javascript file works externally without any jquery, I have tested it.

In my external javascript file, while using jquery, I see the error "$ is not defined" even though I put the library before my reference to my javascript file.

I tried to put my jquery code in a script tag in the head, but that also failed to work. I also tried google and microsofts CDN links for the jquery library, both did not work.

How can I get jquery to work in an external file? I am currently using brackets.io as my code editor.

Comment: If you open your developer tools (usually F12) and look at the network tab, does it load the jquery file successfully?

Comment: `$ not defined` means your page is not reading the jquery file. Could you link to your page?

Comment: That's weird. Please include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Show us the directory contents.